# Does app designed for iOS 7 can work and pass certification for iOS 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I need to start develop iOS application. As I can see design guideline for iOS 7 is totally different from iOS 6.
Can I start develop this new app following guidelines for iOS 7 and be sure that application designed like this will also work on iOS 6 ?
Will this iOS 7 designed app can pass certification requirements to also run on iOS 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends... if in your coding you didn´t use any new framework or anything for ios 7 and in your project you indicate that it´s made for ios 6 too and works on both versions it should pass, anyway, you can see how it looks and works on ios 6 with the xcode ios 6 simulator, it will most certainly not look the same, as the navigation bar, status bar, buttons etc... are different.